# Where is the hardware acceleration in the ICS Emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I thought this was on the way, anybody know how to enable it?

Seems that I can't get a `GLES2.0` context inside the emulator either, but maybe that's just me. `IllegalArgumentException:` No configs match from the egl.

However, the `GLES20 API Demo` included seems to run.

Anyways, even so, none of it seems accelerated or fast then old emulators. Nice update though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android SDK Tools R15 you can enable GPU emulation in 4.0.3 Image.

You need to create a new emulator virtual device and set GPU emulation to true in Hardware properties.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator in ICS doesn't include hardware acceleration.

(The bug to provide that is still open: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6816)

That said, it does allow hardware acceleration for apps when they're running on a phone. (This feature was actually introduced in Honeycomb for tablets.)

Comment: However, they demo'd the functionality 4-5 months ago, and said it was about that far away.

So I guess what I'm asking is not "is it officially released" it's more about "is there a flag or option to enable it somehow"

Comment: No, there is no flag to enable it right now. It has not shipped in any form.

Comment: 10-21 00:25:46.455: D/gralloc_goldfish(794): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Oh google, why you tease so much... lol

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK Add hw.gpu.enabled hardware property on August 26, 2011's [commit](https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/commit/cb88e79ecbd16dea5f2201fd12320db5945db83e).
"the emulator can (sort of) do emulation but you need a system image 
that supports it. We haven't released any yet. If it was ready we would have announced it." said with Xavier Ducrohet On  Oct 20, 2011.
[Ice cream sandwich gpu emulation issue](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5df7e72bff9f088/c932a2c59e6ca9be?show_docid=c932a2c59e6ca9be&pli=1).
As of now, I can't find a system image supports it.